# Can 3rd raw moment be represented with central moments only?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I was presented with following task: "Express 3rd regular moment of a random variable X using its central moments." and given a solution: $$\alpha_3=\mu_3+3\mu_1\mu_2+\mu_1^3$$

I believe the solution is incorrect. After some simple calculations I got:
$$ \alpha_3=\mu_3+3\alpha_1\mu_2+\alpha_1^3$$
where $\alpha_n$ stands for $n$-th raw moment and $\mu_n$ for $n$-th central moment. I understand that expected value is often marked with $\mu$ (as well as my $\alpha_1$ or $\operatorname{E}X$), but since $\mu \ne \mu_1$ I don't think that matters.

What would be correct answer to this question?

Comment: Can you quote the textbook's claim verbatim and cite the book?

Comment: My textbooks defines the task as (translated) "Express 3rd regular moment of random variable X using its central moments." and offers a final solution: $\alpha_3=\mu_3+3\mu_1\mu_2+\mu_1^3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first central moment is always $0;$ hence an expression involving only central moments must be determined by the second and higher central moments.

Suppose you have such an expression, a function of the central moments of the distribution of a random variable $X.$ Then what about $c+X,$ where $c$ is constant, i.e. $c$ is not random? The third raw moment of $X$ and that of $c+X$ differ from each other, but all of their central moments are the same. So your function of the central moments is unchanged by the addition of $c,$ whereas the third raw moment changes when $c$ is added.

(However, it is possible to express the $n$th raw moment as a function of the first moment and the second and higher central moments.)

Comment: I understand that what you said in 2nd paragraph is a proof of inability to produce expression given in the task.